# In geometry nodes, how to assign vertices of mesh primitives to a vertex group?

Tags: vertex-groups, geometry-nodes

1. On default cube, add a new vertex group, call it Group, leave it empty.
2. On default cube, add geometry nodes modifier and bevel modifier. Make bevel modifier use the vertex group.

[image]

3. In geometry nodes add attribute fill node, use Group attribute and set it to 1. Magically, the cube will now get beveled.

[image]

4. Replace the original geometry with a mesh primitive, for example a different cube. Weirdly, the cube is no longer beveled.

[image]

How can I assign vertices of a mesh primitive to a vertex group? I have checked the spreadsheet and it looks like the vertices are actually in the vertex group, but the bevel modifier does not react to it.

[image]

Comment: Looks like there is no way to initialize actual vertex groups on instanced geometry. I'd say it is a current limitation of the system

Comment: I agree with Gorgious. AFAIK there is no way to do it now.

Comment: The thought crossed my mind too. Oh well.

Comment: If anybody's interested, this is known issue, with some work being done on it; see https://developer.blender.org/T88334 .  Basically, in 2.93 GN is using instancing code to improve performance, but the instancing doesn't allow for full mesh properties.  At least, that's my amateur understanding.